# How to write conditions in Elastic Search

Tags: node.js, elasticsearch

I want to write a conditional query in elastic search. This is my complete query but its not working as expected.

like:

```
 {"query":{"bool":{"must":[{"nested":{"path":"ticket_group","score_mode":"max","inner_hits":{"from":0,"size":10000},"query":{"bool":{"must":[{"range":{"ticket_group.available":{"gte":1}}},{"bool":{"minimum_should_match":1,"should":[{"bool":{"must":[{"match":{"ticket_group.customer_id":1}},{"match":{"ticket_group.ticket_type":1}},{"match":{"ticket_group.individual_purchase":1}}]}},{"bool":{"must_not":[{"match":{"ticket_group.ticket_type":1}}]}}]}},{"terms":{"ticket_group.ticket_type":[1,3,4]}}]}}}}]}},"size":10,"from":0}
```

I want to perform search individual_purchase=1 only if ticket_type=1.
How can i write this query?

Comment: What should happen if ticket_type != 1 ?

Comment: no need to check next condtion..Thanks

Comment: but all documents should be returned if that's the case or none at all?

Comment: then all tickets will be returned

Comment: Your query should work just as is imo. If it doesn't, I'd suggest creating a gist with a complete mapping, some sample documents, the query you tested and explaining why the results are not correct. So far, using your query, I haven't been able to reproduce the issue.

Comment: It's working.. it was my mistake..Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Then you can do something like this:

```
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "minimum_should_match": 1,
      "should": [
        {
          "bool": {
            "must": [
              {
                "match": {
                  "ticket_group.ticket_type": 1
                }
              },
              {
                "match": {
                  "ticket_group.individual_purchase": 1
                }
              }
            ]
          }
        },
        {
          "bool": {
            "must_not": [
              {
                "match": {
                  "ticket_group.ticket_type": 1
                }
              }
            ]
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

The above query translates to:

- either `ticket_type = 1` AND `individual_purchase = 1`
- or `ticket_type != 1`

Comment: Val its still returning ticket having ticket_type=1 and individual_purchase!=1